# How to improve app availability in android play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an android app. I have added it to the Google Play Store. The minSdk has been set to 10 and targetSdk is 15.

I recently asked some of my friends to test it by downloading it from the Play Store. Most of them especially using Samsung mobile phones told me that they get an error that it is not available in the play store.

I know that the app will be not available for devices with versions of the android that doesn't meet the app's minSdk.

After asking some of my friends to download the app I was able to know that some of my friends using android 2.3.6 was not able to download the app. Another person used Samsung Galaxy Champ Duos (Its gingerbread but i dont know the exact version of android) was not able to find it in the play store.

I googled about this but was not able to find any solution.

The permissions I request are the following. I believe that these are general permissions (General as in most mobile phones should have these features.)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

The uses-feature tags that are used by my app are listed below.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
```

So my question is how can I make my app available to more devices ? I am planning a launch for my app soon. I dont want potential users to just give up on the app just because they cant find it in the play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set minSDK  to 10, any device which its version below than 10 can't install your app.

In your case may be other limitation about screen density of some device feature. Check your request feature on your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The mobile phone that couldn't download the app was using Android 2.3.6 that is SDK version 10.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have uses-feature tags in your manifest?  If so, you could be eliminating a lot of devices, don't add those unless your app will not work at all without them.  Same for screen size support tags.

Otherwise the play store provides a way to see the list of supported devices-  its under the APK section, a blue link under supported devices.

Comment: I havent thought about the uses tag before...
I have now edited the question and added the permissions to the question. I dont think that would be the reason why they cant get the app from the store. The permissions are almost general...

Comment: Posting the above comment I didn't notice the uses-feature. I just went through the uses-permission. I have posted the uses-features too in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use minSdk at least 8 to support max android device

Comment: That is true. But the issue here is that a person using sdk 10 was not able to find the app even though the apps minSdk is 10..

Comment: This assumes that he can.  The lower the better, but if you have an API call that requires 9 or higher then you can't lower this (unless you can work without that call.

Answer (score 0):

> You can search the your app on Google Play with your package name.

**For example**

You give packagename="com.xxxxx.app" in AndroidManifest.xml then you can search your app on google play by entering **com.xxxx.app**

It will be easy for you but If its minSDK is 10 then it will not viewable in search result below SDK 10 version.

To make available app for SDK version 8 to 17 write this in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```